# SwiftUI - EditMode and PresentationMode Environment

Tags: swiftui

How can I show a form in EditMode and PresentationMode Environment?

Example:

When user tap on EditButton, it should show Form in EditMode, with text files as input, and changes Navigation Title

```
import SwiftUI

struct FormView: View {

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {


        Form {


            Text("Placeholder")

            // On EditMode it should show this
            // TextField("Placeholder", text: Value)

           }

        .navigationBarTitle("Presentation Mode")
        // On EditMode it should show this
        // .navigationBarTitle("Edit Mode")

        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())






 }


    }
}

struct FormView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        FormView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In this case, when using `editMode` environment variable, for some reason `EditButton()` doesn't work on its own. Whereas, the `editMode` is toggled correctly when a custom button is used.

Interestingly, if the `EditButton()` is added along with the custom button (for testing purposes), after the custom button is used to toggle the value at least once, the `EditButton()` also springs to life and provides the expected behavior.

The following code snippet works fine for me:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TempView2: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode

    @State var textValue : String = "abc"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $textValue)
                    .disabled(.inactive == self.editMode?.wrappedValue)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .foregroundColor((.active == self.editMode?.wrappedValue) ? Color.red : Color.green)
                    .navigationBarTitle(.inactive == self.editMode?.wrappedValue ? "Presentation Mode" : "Edit Mode")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                        HStack {
                            //Spacer()
                            //EditButton()
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                self.editMode?.wrappedValue = .active == self.editMode?.wrappedValue ? .inactive : .active
                            }) {
                                Text(.active == self.editMode?.wrappedValue ? "Done" : "Edit")
                            }
                            Spacer()
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Found that wrapping the custom edit button's action in: withAnimation {  } it restores the animation from the default button.

Answer (score 0):

That is one way of achieving an editable form:

```
struct FormView: View {

    @State private var isEditing = false
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Placeholder",
                          text: $text)
                    .disabled(!isEditing)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(isEditing ? "Edit Mode" : "Presentation Mode")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(isEditing ? "Save" : "Edit") {
                self.isEditing.toggle()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use the EditMode Environment