# SwiftUI detect edit mode

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've returned to iOS development after a while and I'm rebuilding my Objective-C app from scratch in SwiftUI.

One of the things I want to do is use the default Edit Mode to allow entries in a List (backed by Core Data on CloudKit) to switch between a NavigationLink to a detail view and an edit view.

The main approach seems to be to handle it through a if statement that detects edit mode. The Apple documentation provides the following snippet for this approach on this developer page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editmode

```
@Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
@State private var name = "Maria Ruiz"

var body: some View {
    Form {
        if editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
        } else {
            Text(name)
        }
    }
    .animation(nil, value: editMode?.wrappedValue)
    .toolbar { // Assumes embedding this view in a NavigationView.
        EditButton()
    }
}
```

However, this does not work (I've embedded the snippet in a NavigationView as assumed).
Is this a bug in Xcode 13.4.1? iOS 15.5? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Update1:**

Based on Asperi's answer I came up with the following generic view to handle my situation:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditableRow: View {
#if os(iOS)
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
#endif
    
    @State var rowView: AnyView
    @State var detailView: AnyView
    @State var editView: AnyView

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink{
            if(editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true){
                editView
            }
            else{
                detailView
            }
            
        }label: {
            rowView
        }
    }
}

struct EditableRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                EditButton()
                EditableRow(rowView: AnyView(Text("Row")), detailView: AnyView(Text("Detail")), editView: AnyView(Text("Edit")))
            }
        }
    }
```

The preview works as expected, but this works partially in my real app. When I implement this the NavigationLink works when not in Edit Mode, but doesn't do anything when in Edit Mode. I also tried putting the whole NavigationLink in the if statement but that had the same result.
Any idea why this isn't working?

**Update2:**

Something happens when it's inside a List. When I change the preview to this is shows the behavior I'm getting:

```
struct EditableRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                EditableRow(rowView: AnyView(GroupRow(title: "Title", subTitle: "Subtitle", type: GroupType.personal)), detailView: AnyView(EntryList()), editView: AnyView(Text("Edit")))
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                HStack{
#if os(iOS)
                    EditButton()
#endif
                }
            )
         }
    }
}
```

**Update3:**

Found this answer: [SwiftUI - EditMode and PresentationMode Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084501/swiftui-editmode-and-presentationmode-environment)

This claims the default EditButton is broken, which seems to be true. Replacing the default button with a custom one works (be sure to add a withAnimation{} block to get all the behavior from the stock button.
But it still doesn't work for my NavigationLink...

**Update4:**

Ok, tried passing an "isEditing" Bool to the above View, not to depend on the Environment variable being available. This works as long as the View (a ForEach within a List in my case) isn't in "Editing Mode" whatever happens at that point breaks any NavigationLink it seems.

**Update5:**

Basically my conclusion is that the default Edit Mode is meant to edit the "List Object" as a whole enabling moving and deleting of rows. In this mode Apple feels that editing the rows themselves isn't something you'd want to do. I can see this perspective.
If, however, you still want to enable a NavigationLink from a row in Edit Mode, this answer should help:
[How to make SwiftUI NavigationLink work in edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236010/how-to-make-swiftui-navigationlink-work-in-edit-mode)

Asperi's answer does cover why the detection doesn't work. I did find that Edit Mode detection does work better when setting the edit mode manually and not using the default EditButton, see the answer above for details.

Comment: @Asperi gave a great workaround. However because it doesn't match the documentation I've filed a bug report to Apple: FB10429307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is on same level so environment is not visible, because it is activated for sub-views.

A possible solution is to separate dependent part into standalone view, like

```
    Form {
        InternalView()
    }
    .toolbar {
        EditButton()
    }
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestEditModeInForm.swift)

Answer (score 2):

I've got it to work by using a `.simultaneousGesture` on the `EditButton` and playing with a `@State` wrapper.

```
struct EditingFix: View {
@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
@State var showDeleteButton = false

var body: some View {
    Text("hello")
        .toolbar(content: {
            if showDeleteButton {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading, content: {
                    Label("Remove selected", systemImage: "trash")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                })
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing, content: {
                EditButton()
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({
                        showDeleteButton.toggle()
                    }))
            })
        })
        .onChange(of: showDeleteButton, perform: { isEditing in
            editMode?.wrappedValue = isEditing ? .active : .inactive
        })
        .animation(.default, value: editMode?.wrappedValue) // Restore the default smooth animation for list selection and others
}
```

I can definitly say that `EditButton` is not using the same `EditMode` environment as what we get when invoking `@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode`. So we have to do it all ourselves if we want to get the benefit of the `EditButton`. Mainly the localized Edit text that it displays in my case.

**Alternatively**

The above method led to some weird behavior where the `EditButton` `editMode` seemed to conflict in some situation with the `@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode`. I'd advise you use your own logic for editing using the reliable `.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)`. This way you can do whatever you want with the binding that control editing.

```
struct EditingFix: View {
@State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
@State var isEditing = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if editMode.isEditing {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        Text("World")
        Button("Toggle hello", action: {
            isEditing.toggle()
        })
    }
    .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
    .onChange(of: isEditing, perform: { isEditing in
        editMode = isEditing ? .active : .inactive
    })
    .animation(.default, value: editMode)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

@Asperi's answer worked well for me. However I wanted to still be able to access the editMode in the same hierarchy. As a workaround I created the following:

[image: Example]

#### Usage

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                if editMode.isEditing == true {
                    Color.red
                } else {
                    Color.blue
                }
            }
            .editModeFix($editMode)
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Implementation

```swift
extension View {
    func editModeFix(_ editMode: Binding<EditMode>) -> some View {
        modifier(EditModeFixViewModifier(editMode: editMode))
    }
}

private struct EditModeFixView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode)
    private var editModeEnvironment
    
    @Binding
    var editMode: EditMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
            .onChange(of: editModeEnvironment?.wrappedValue) { editModeEnvironment in
                if let editModeEnvironment = editModeEnvironment {
                    editMode = editModeEnvironment
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: editMode) {
                editModeEnvironment?.wrappedValue = $0
            }
    }
}

private struct EditModeFixViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding
    var editMode: EditMode
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay {
                EditModeFixView(editMode: $editMode)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work with a NavigationLink?

Comment: Haven’t tried, give it a go and let us know

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to decompose the main view into views containing each list to be edited, then provide an editMode environment variable to each decomposed view. Here's some code:

```
struct ListContainer: View {
    @State private var foods = ["apples", "pizza", "okra"]
    @State private var activities = ["cricket", "skiing", "pickleball"]
    @State private var showFoodEditor: EditMode = .inactive
    @State private var showActivitiesEditor: EditMode = .inactive
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FoodList(foods: $foods)
                .environment(\.editMode, $showFoodEditor)
            ActivitiesList(activities: $activities)
                .environment(\.editMode, $showActivitiesEditor)
        }
    }
}
struct FoodList: View {
    @Binding var foods: Array<String>
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                HStack {
                    Text("Choose favorites")
                    Spacer()
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
            ForEach (foods, id:\.self) { food in
                Text(food)
            }
            .onMove(perform: {from, to in
                //Perform move work here
            })
        }
    }
}
struct ActivitiesList: View {
    @Binding var activities: Array<String>
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                HStack {
                    Text("Delete activities")
                    Spacer()
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
            ForEach (activities, id:\.self) { activity in
                Text(activity)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: { indexDeleted in
                //do your delete work here
            })
        }
    }
}
```